# GWT JSR 303 client validation

Tags: validation, gwt, bean-validation

I'm developing a GWT application with a Spring backend that uses JSR 303 validation. The application can go offline and use the browser HTML5/Gears database instead.

What is the best way to implement the client validation? So far I have found gwt-validation framework (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/) but it seems it is no longer active.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

There is a new GWT official project to support JSR 303 Bean Validation ([link here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation)). IMO this is the way to go once the project is mature enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our validation framework is a client and server-side data input validation framework. Its roles is to ensure business rules compliance of data passed from the clients to the server.

The validation framework uses the GWT Validation project which implements the "JSR 303: Bean Validation" specification.

The idea is to decorate Data Transfer Objects (DTO) classes and fields with JSR303 annotations to describe their validity rules.

1. Each Data Transfer Objects must be decorated with its own validation annotations.
2. Each server-side service implementation must validate Data Transfer Objects it receives from the client.

On the client side, to use GWT-Validation in your project you'll need to add (along with the jar on your classpath) to your GWT module xml file

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.validation.Validation" />
```

Ensure DTOs implement com.google.gwt.validation.client.interfaces.IValidatable

To validate on the client side use

```
com.google.gwt.validation.client.interfaces.IValidator.validateProperty((T) model, propertyName);
```

On the server side use

```
com.google.gwt.validation.server.ServerValidator
```

It's a bit of work to set this up properly but then it works perfectly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!
I assume the link I was looking for in the answer is  http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/, right?

Comment: GWT official project to support JSR 303 works fine since GWT2.4 and does not require you to implement IValidatable, you can find all you need here : http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation. Both client and server side covered with one annotation on your domain objects or DTO's.

Comment: is this a dead project? I want to use it but dont know if I can trust it!?

Comment: gwt-validation @ gwt-validation.googlecode.com is not dead.  In fact, over the last year or so, there's be somewhat of a revival.  The aim is for there to be no need for any special implementations or actions on behalf of the implementor.

Answer (score 6):

GWT 2.5 has a new feature just for this :
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation

It uses the Hibernate Validator.

1) You will need to extend AbstractGwtValidatorFactory and apply your bean e.g. :

```
public final class SampleValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {

  /**
   * Validator marker for the Validation Sample project. Only the classes and groups listed
   * in the {@link GwtValidation} annotation can be validated.
   */
  @GwtValidation(Person.class)
  public interface GwtValidator extends Validator {
  }

  @Override
  public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator() {
    return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
  }
}
```

2) Then add this to your gwt.xml :

```
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
<replace-with
  class="yourpackage.SampleValidatorFactory">
  <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

3) Validate your bean

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);
```

Comment: oops, I saw the question has been updated with a link similar to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it yet, but GWT 2.1 includes some Validation support.

Check the ShowCase [example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellValidation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Carlos. That example shows how you can create a custom cell that manually validates user input. What I want to avoid is having to write my validation twice in the client and in the server.

Comment: @Javier, if you care enough about the validity of your data to perform validation anywhere, you absolutely should do the validation on the server side. Client-side validation is just a nice feature to save your users' time and efforts.